# Random number guessing game prints unnecessary line

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I have a project that I am working on in school. When I run the program, it gives me everything I ask, except the fact that it prints "The number is bigger" above the answer. Is there anything I am missing? Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numberOfGuesses = 0;
        int x = 0;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

        while (x != 1) {
            System.out.print("Guess an integer between 1 and 100: " );
            int guessedNumber = reader.nextInt();
            if (guessedNumber < randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("The number is bigger");
            }
            if (guessedNumber > randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("The number is smaller");
            }
            else{
            x++;
            }
            numberOfGuesses++;
        }
        System.out.println("You're correct! It took" + " " + numberOfGuesses + " " + "guesses.");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it works? if guess is 10 and random is 20: 10 is less than 20 so print "the number is bigger". 10 is not greater than 20 so increment x and end the game.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if (guessedNumber < randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("The number is bigger");
        }
        if (guessedNumber > randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("The number is smaller");
        }
        else{
        x++;
        }
```

TO

```
        if (guessedNumber < randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("The number is bigger");
        } else if (guessedNumber > randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("The number is smaller");
        } else{
            x++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the number is bigger, your second if fails and goes to its else part which increments x to 1 and exists the program. put the second if statement as else if.

```
        if (guessedNumber < randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("The number is bigger");
        }
        else if (guessedNumber > randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("The number is smaller");
        }
        else{
        x++;
        }
```